# Transform a tab using value as header with R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, filter

I need to transform a table that looks like this :

| city | vote | name | vote | name | vote | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 83 | name2 | 17 | name1 | 5 | name3 |
| c2 | 55 | name1 | 45 | name3 | 33 | name2 |
| c3 | 77 | name3 | 23 | name2 | 14 | name1 |

into this :

| city | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | vote1 c1 | vote2 c1 | vote3 c1 |
| c2 | vote1 c2 | vote2 c2 | vote3 c2 |
| c3 | vote1 c3 | vote3 c3 | vote3 c3 |

Where voteX is the vote for the nameX.

using R (I can't use anything else).

I really don't know how can I do that, what is the best way to do ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table` to melt long and then dcast:

```
# load library
library(data.table)

# set df to data.table
setDT(df)

# melt, and then dcast
dcast(
  melt(df, id="city", measure.vars = patterns(c("^vote", "^name"))),
  city~value2, value.var="value1"
)
```

Output:

```
Key: <city>
     city name1 name2 name3
   <char> <int> <int> <int>
1:     c1    17    83     5
2:     c2    55    33    45
3:     c3    14    23    7
```

Comment: I need to use it on more than 3 lines and with more than 3 names, is it possible to use it with more datas ? Thanks you

Comment: there is nothing in the solution that would limit it to 3 rows.. If it is not working on your actual data, you'll probably have to provide an example of the real data that is closer to what it actually looks like.